# VBA error matching date from table and date from query when date has leading zero eg 01/04 or 02/04

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access

I have a query in MS Access called qryRMCountStudentsBySessionWP.  The results are shown below.

[image]

I have some VBA code shown below.  Basically if the Timetable_Date, Timetable_Session and Location match Exam_Date, Exam_Session and Exam_Location of a record in a table called Invigilation, then changes are made to that record's start time.

This works fabulously for 30/03/2020 and 31/03/2020 but not any of the April dates.  I think this is because of leading zeros but I just can't figure out how to fix it.  Any ideas?

```
Private Sub wordProcessing()

    Dim dbs                As Database
    Dim name               As String
    Dim SQL                As String
    Dim rstAllSessions     As Recordset

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

         SQL = "SELECT Timetable_Date, Timetable_Session, Location, CountOfStudent_Ref FROM qryRMCountStudentsBySessionWP;"


    Set rstAllSessions = dbs.OpenRecordset(SQL)

    rstAllSessions.MoveFirst

    Do Until rstAllSessions.EOF  ' for each sesson update invigilation table


         If rstAllSessions.Fields(3) >= 10 Then

            If rstAllSessions.Fields(1) = "A" Then
                dbs.Execute "UPDATE Invigilation SET Start_Time = TimeValue('08:30:00'), Notes = 'WP Exam with 10 or more students' WHERE Invigilation.Exam_Date = #" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Date & "# AND Invigilation.Exam_Location = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Location & "'" & "AND  Invigilation.Exam_Session = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Session & "'" & ";", dbFailOnError
            Else
                dbs.Execute "UPDATE Invigilation SET Start_Time = TimeValue('13:00:00'), Notes = 'WP Exam with 10 or more students' WHERE Invigilation.Exam_Date = #" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Date & "# AND Invigilation.Exam_Location = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Location & "'" & "AND  Invigilation.Exam_Session = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Session & "'" & ";", dbFailOnError
            End If

         ElseIf rstAllSessions.Fields(3) >= 5 Then

            If rstAllSessions.Fields(1) = "A" Then
                dbs.Execute "UPDATE Invigilation SET Start_Time = TimeValue('08:35:00'), Notes = 'WP Exam with 5 or more students' WHERE Invigilation.Exam_Date = #" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Date & "# AND Invigilation.Exam_Location = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Location & "'" & "AND  Invigilation.Exam_Session = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Session & "'" & ";", dbFailOnError
            Else
                dbs.Execute "UPDATE Invigilation SET Start_Time = TimeValue('13:05:00'), Notes = 'WP Exam with 5 or more students' WHERE Invigilation.Exam_Date = #" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Date & "# AND Invigilation.Exam_Location = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Location & "'" & "AND  Invigilation.Exam_Session = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Session & "'" & ";", dbFailOnError
            End If

        ElseIf rstAllSessions.Fields(3) > 1 Then

            If rstAllSessions.Fields(1) = "A" Then
                dbs.Execute "UPDATE Invigilation SET Start_Time = TimeValue('08:40:00'), Notes = 'WP Exam with >1 and <5 students' WHERE Invigilation.Exam_Date = #" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Date & "# AND Invigilation.Exam_Location = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Location & "'" & "AND  Invigilation.Exam_Session = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Session & "'" & ";", dbFailOnError
            Else
                dbs.Execute "UPDATE Invigilation SET Start_Time = TimeValue('13:10:00'), Notes = 'WP Exam with >1 and <5 students' WHERE Invigilation.Exam_Date = #" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Date & "# AND Invigilation.Exam_Location = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Location & "'" & "AND  Invigilation.Exam_Session = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Session & "'" & ";", dbFailOnError
            End If

        Else

           If rstAllSessions.Fields(1) = "A" Then
                dbs.Execute "UPDATE Invigilation SET Start_Time = TimeValue('08:45:00'), Notes = 'WP Exam with 1 student' WHERE Invigilation.Exam_Date = #" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Date & "# AND Invigilation.Exam_Location = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Location & "'" & "AND  Invigilation.Exam_Session = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Session & "'" & ";", dbFailOnError
            Else
                dbs.Execute "UPDATE Invigilation SET Start_Time = TimeValue('13:15:00'), Notes = 'WP Exam with 1 student' WHERE Invigilation.Exam_Date = #" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Date & "# AND Invigilation.Exam_Location = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Location & "'" & "AND  Invigilation.Exam_Session = " & "'" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Session & "'" & ";", dbFailOnError
            End If

        End If

       '  doesn't do dates with leading 0s?????

       rstAllSessions.MoveNext

    Loop

    rstAllSessions.Close
    dbs.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date values are numeric, thus no leading zeroes. But you must pass properly formatted *string expressions* for the date values when concatenating:

```vb
"UPDATE Invigilation SET Start_Time = TimeSerial(13,15,0), Notes = 'WP Exam with 1 student' WHERE Invigilation.Exam_Date = #" & Format(rstAllSessions!Timetable_Date, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND Invigilation.Exam_Location = '" & rstAllSessions!Location & "' AND  Invigilation.Exam_Session = '" & rstAllSessions!Timetable_Session & "';"
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you!  That has been driving me nuts for ages!